# socket.emit function not working for intranet

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to make an online game with nodejs and socket.io. I have developed the game until player initialization and gamearea initialization steps, which works fine on localhost. it is not working on other computer on my local network. **The server is only able to emit on the first host connected.**

`handleplayerinit` function handles the initialization of player which will emit info about online players to all connected hosts which works fine for localhost but for some other computer server will emit player info to initially joined host only.

I store every players' position in a map named `players` which is a member of game class. Structure of player map is as below

> game.players={"socketid"=>playerobject}

I also store each connected socket in game.sockets member

> game.sockets={"socketid"=>socketobject}

Game class definition is in the other file. I have not included that file because I am sure that problem resides in `handleplayerinit` function

In `handleplayerinit` I iterate over every socket and then to each socket I send info about players that are online. But for intranet it seems to send data to sockets of initially connected host only.

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Game = require(__dirname + '/game.js');

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
//send file to user
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/testgame.html');
});
//after successfull conncetion
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  game.startgame(socket);
  socket.on('planet position', handleplanetPosition);
  socket.on('player position', handleplayerPosition);
  socket.on('init player', handleplayerinit);
});
//listen to port 3000
http.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

//start game
const game = new Game();

function handleplanetPosition(planets) {
  game.planets = planets;
}

function handleplayerPosition(playerpos, socketid) {
  game.players.set(socketid, playerpos);
  game.sockets.forEach(socket => {
    game.players.forEach(function(player, socketid) {
      socket.emit("update playerpos", socketid, player);
    });
  });
}

function handleplayerinit(socketid, player) {
  game.players.set(socketid, player);
  game.sockets.forEach(socket => {
    game.players.forEach(function(player, socketid) {
      socket.emit("playerinit complete", socketid, player);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that every computers can access your websocket server ?

Comment: yes every computer will get html file but only the first connected host will get info about total players meaning server is only emitting data to first connected hosts' sockets

Comment: io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket)  is this event getting called for multiple players?

Comment: I found the problem. Here i am emitting two events, player init when new player joins and other one update playerpos which every time player changes position. So it may happen that on client side first update function is called before initialisation function and it was the case here. So i was updating player position before initialisation them. I solved the problem by implementing promise on initialisation step.